# Mongoose many to many relation and circular structure to JSON

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to create a classic Articles/Categories association with mongoose.
Everything works fine, but since I am trying to expose the query results as JSON, I get a `Converting circular structure to JSON` error.
I know the issue is related in cross referencing models, but I don't know how to solve this.
Here are my model schemas.

```
var ArticleSchema = new Schema({
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    content: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    user: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    categories: [{
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Category'
    }]
});

ArticleSchema.statics.load = function(id, cb) {
    this.findOne({
        _id: id
    }).populate('user', 'name username').populate('categories', 'title').exec(cb);
};

/**
 * Category Schema
 */
var CategorySchema = new Schema({
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    user: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }
},
{
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
    toJSON: { virtuals: true }
});

/**
 * Virtual Schema
 */

var articles = CategorySchema.virtual('articles');
articles.get(function () {
  return Article.find({categories : { $eq: this }});
});
```

Comment: Why are you using MongoDB if you just want to structure in typical relational modelling? Perhaps if you gave the actual problem you wanted to solve then you would get a solution ( as suited to a NoSQL modelling response ). Otherwise just use relational modelling with a database engine that supports that. Or you could actually consider not using relational modelling, which is why you should be here in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be like you have circular references, this mean that the json you create is calling it self in somere.. Im not sure if this line could be the problem:

```
articles.get(function () {
  return Article.find({categories : { $eq: this }});
});
```

why dont you try with a hardcore value in $eq ??

Comment: I am sure the problem is there: Article is populating categories, while Category is populating articles. I know the issue, but I am looking for a solution.

Comment: sorry the missunderstanding.. so.. may I’m wrong, but when you do $eq: this, "this" in that moment is the anonymous function you created, so you are calling recursively the same function or not ?.

Comment: did you find a solution? i'm down to deleting fields on the _doc and it's nasty

Comment: In his particular example, is the _this_ word, that is pointing to the same function that is returning the reference to _this_.  So if you mention _doc is because you already have a doc, in that case you can call `.toJSON()` method @dcsan